# The right way of using RAID on a desktop computer?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid

Ok I have two SSD disks 256 GB each and just want to make sure my desktop never ever ever gives me Read Error or dies all together.

I am totally fine having 256 GB of space on my desktop, but just want to make sure my data is protected against disk failures and read errors. I am linux guy. Which RAID should I use and how? Should I divide these two disks in to two partitions each and use RAID 6 or should I use RAID 1?

Does RAID fixes read errors automatically (heals it self) or do I need to do something manually to prevent Read Errors? Will my desktop become slower or faster with RAID?

Straight forward tutorial "For Dummies" would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just use R1, this idea 'Should I divide these two disks in to two partitions each and use RAID 6' is crazy/unworkable anyway. Use a hardware disk controller if you can, software R1 for boot can be more complex to recover.